# Два фоновых блока с трансформацией

Tags: html, css

Есть 2 блока которые идут следом друг под другом, имеют фоновое изображение и трансформацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую с `clip-path`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-1 {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/700/300) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  min-height: 300px;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
}


.bg-2 {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/400) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  min-height: 200px;
  
  
  margin-top: -20%;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
}


.section {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="section bg-1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nobis possimus, ipsam consectetur et quo veritatis, quas magni asperiores fugit!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="section bg-2">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nobis possimus, ipsam consectetur et quo veritatis, quas magni asperiores fugit!
    </p>
  </div>
```

Но все выглядит отвратительно, еще и у `clip-path` проблемы с кроссбраузерностью.

**Вопрос:** какие есть варианты реализации такой задачи со стандартными прямоугольными изображениями, кроме как использовать уже готовые такие изображения (вырезанные под форму)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может такой вариант подойдет с использованием `transform: rotate(VALUEdeg) skew(VALUEdeg);`

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-1 {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/700/300) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;  
  min-height: 390px;
  margin-top: -15%;
  transform: rotate(-5deg) skew(-5deg);
}


.bg-2 {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/400) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  min-height: 200px;
  
  
  /*margin-top: -20%;*/
  
  transform: rotate(-5deg) skew(-5deg);
}


.section {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  transform: rotate(5deg) skew(5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="section bg-1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nobis possimus, ipsam consectetur et quo veritatis, quas magni asperiores fugit!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="section bg-2">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nobis possimus, ipsam consectetur et quo veritatis, quas magni asperiores fugit!
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: да, спасибо! Пробовала просто `rotate` и фон искажался, как-то и не подумала о `skew`